# Attribute not saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm an absolute beginner on **EF**, and I am stuck with this problem:

I have `2 tables`:
**Toy and Brand**

```
public class Toy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public Brand brand { get; set; }
}
public class Brand
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My DBContext file:

```
public class SOT : DbContext
{ public SOT(): base("name=SOT")
    {

public virtual DbSet<Brand> brands; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Toy> toys { get; set; }
}
```

The Brand data is given in the view, using a dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Toy.brand, new SelectList(Model.BrandsList, "BrandId", "Name"), "Select 
Brand", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This seems to work fine, as shown in the page source:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Toy_Brand" name="Toy.Brand"><option value="">Select 
Brand</option>
<option value="1">LEGO</option>
<option value="2">HASBRO</option>
<option value="5">Fisher Price</option>
</select>
```

The List<> Brandslist used is created here:

```
public class NewToyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Brand> BrandsList { get; set; }
    public Toy Toy { get; set; }
}
```

The view is using this model:

```
@model Spelotheek.ViewModels.NewToyViewModel
```

When I add a record, the Brand field is null.

```
public ActionResult Create(Toy toy)
    {
        _context.Toy.Add(toy);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

All fields, except Brand are saved OK
What am I doing wrong?

thanks,
James

Comment: did you coded the one-to-many relationship in DbContext?

Comment: What do you mean by "except Brand". Brand isn't supposed to be saved. It's in the database already and you don't want to insert a new Brand for each Toy. What matters is whether `Toy.BrandId` is saved correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your solve , you need to say to EF it is foreign key for brand

**migrate again after edit your code**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


public class Toy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("brand")]
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public Brand brand { get; set; }
}
```

note, you will see brand is null in debug but if BrandId is not null, do not worry 
you are right for now after

```
db.SaveChanges()
```

and get Toy from

```
Db.Toys.Include(x=>x.brand).ToList();
```

you will not the brand is not null

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the point. EF will infer the foreign key bij default conventions. Maybe the reason why this answer was accepted is that querying toys `Include`-ing brand *makes it visible* that BrandId  was always saved but they weren't  aware of it. It should be alright without the explicit mapping though.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with BrandId instead of Brand in `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Toy.brand)` like `Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Toy.BrandId)`